# MVC5 App gets 'Internet Explorer cannot display webpage' error (timeout issue?)

Tags: internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-5, session-timeout

Alright so I've ready basically every 'Internet Explorer cannot display webpage' question I can find on this site and I haven't found one that is relavent to this situation as I can tell.  Also this isn't like a lot I've read where it happens during an upload or during some kind of request.

So I have an MVC5 Web App that is working fine for regular use, but when left alone for long periods of time with the browser up and come back and try and do something it just gives the 'Internet Explorer cannot display webpage' page.

I do have custom errors turned on (works well with the error page when receiving regular errors during use).  I'm on IE9 but coworker is also experiencing on IE10.  What we'd like to happen is if user isn't logged in it go to the login page.  I have a custom authorization attribute that is placed on methods in the controller that does checking for this and redirects to login page (if it's working correctly which from what I can tell it seems to be)

Comment: Does any browser currently redirect to the login page when the session times out?

Comment: It is a possibility that redirect on session timeout isn't working at all.  I'm not sure if it's working on other browsers or not.  It's a sort of interntal usage thing where we're only required to adheer to IE & end users only use IE (will move away in future, but it's what's expected at the moment)......Do you have a suggestion/link/etc. on how to do good session timeout redirect?  Thanks for the help

Comment: Alright so I tried the whole SessionExpireAttribute thing I found on here somewhere, but that doesn't work....I tried debugging with that attribute set and it never makes it to the OnActionExecuting method, simply straight to the 'Internet Explorer cannot display webpage' page

Comment: The following is pretty good write-up which tries to cover and explain all of the potentials 'gotchas' in this area: http://markfreedman.com/index.php/2012/02/28/handling-session-and-authentication-timeouts-in-asp-net-mvc/  Be sure to look at his code very closely -- do not dismiss just because you see him using a `SessionExportFilterAttribute`

Comment: Thanks for the link, I checked it out and modified my SessionExportFilterAttribute to what is on that page and also added the other method there, however, the issue still remains. I'm not entirely sure how to implement the javascript ones or if it'd even fix this situation......basically to help test this I've set the timeout to real low and launch from visual studio and let the browser just sit there after I log in with a user.  Upon clicking any link or whatever on the page 'Internet Explorer cannot display webpage'